# java.lang.RuntimeException: Error processing transaction request: replacement transaction underpriced Output from Server

Tags: transactions, web3j, java

I am generating transactions in a contract I deployed in the Rinkeby network and the first 300 or 400 transactions had no errors and I received the txHash, but when I continued I got this following error. My application is developed with web3j and java

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error processing transaction request: replacement transaction underpriced Output from Server
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you face this issue, it can be solved by two things (that I am aware of):

1. make sure to increase the gasPrice by 10-20%. This not given on the ETh paper but this how the miners generally work.
2. The other way round is to increase the nonce and then redo the transaction.

Comment: But if I do, for example 1000 transactions per day, and for each transaction it will increase 10% to 20%, will not it produce an error?

Comment: @NicolasFloresMuñoz if all your 1000 transaction fail for the first time then yes all will need a 10-20% increase on the original transaction gas fee. Also, you can also batch you Process thus doing less transaction (this is just a recommendation, I am not aware of your contract details)

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you have a pending transaction in the transaction pool. You can check this via `eth.pendingTransactions`. If you're using the same nonce like used in the pending transaction, the node will try to replace it. But this will only work if the gasPrice is larger than the old gasPrice.